# Unable to build hello-jni

Tags: android, android-ndk

On cygwin terminal acess `/cygwindrive/c/User/Usuario/android-ndk-r9d/samples/hello-jni`. Try build `hello-jni` whit `ndk-build` and appears this error:

```
 The system can not find the path specified.
 make.exe: *** [libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver] Error 1
```

My path it is already configure

```
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_3\bin;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;
C:\a‌​pp\Usuário\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin; C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\
Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\‌​System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Live\Shared;C:\Users\Usuário\android-sdks\platform-tools;
C:\Users\Usuário\androi‌​d-sdks\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Users\Usuário\android-ndk-r9d;C:\cygwin64\bin
```

Comment: And? There is literally nothing here to help you. Post your makefile? Post something else? We can't read minds.

Comment: i try see if my configure its already.. i already have install again

Comment: Yes, but what does your makefile look like?

Comment: i don`t have makefile yet, i try build the sample from android-ndk package

Comment: Is that the *entire* output from the command?

Comment: update with all output

Comment: Do you have compilers on your path? Can you post your path?

Comment: Can you put *that* into your question as well?

Comment: i had put inside the question

Comment: What is the compile and link command? You should see a `--sysyroot` to bring in headers and libraries. Also, on Windows, just use the Windows tools. There's no need for Cygwin or MinGW.  They are just another layer of problems. If you want to feel like Unix or Linux, then use a Unix or Linux VM.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar error. In my case, i have downloaded the ndk for windows-x86_64. To fix the error, the **Application.mk** in **HelloJni** should be updated as followed:

`APP_ABI := all` -> `APP_ABI := all64`

Check which ndk-version you'd downloaded. You have to enable NDK-LOG to see the ndk-calls with the wrong paths!

Comment: I'm not convinced the above work around is correct. For R10d, Android added ARM64, MIPS64 and x86_64. See [Developers, start your 64-bit engines](http://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/XG1WmNDMe8H). Those are new platforms, and they correspond to `APP_ABI := arm64 mips64 x86_64`

Comment: Hi jww, thank you for the hint! I have update the Application.mk and its APP_ABI to **all64** and **x86_64** afterwards. The HelloJni has successfully built. But when deployed to the Android device, there was an error:  `E/AndroidRuntime(2032): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load hello-jni: findLibrary returned null`

Comment: I've just done another test with different value set for **APP_ABI**. Only **all64** works in my case, without renaming the folders in prebuilt. Answer is updated.